# HTML5 audio file fails to play, with Invalid Source error message

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, mime-types, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to test if some audio files we currently have, can be played via HTML5.

The html code is as follows:

```
<audio width="720" height="405" controls src="https://machinename/media/play?ID=2" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

When the page loads, it seems to be doing something, and later fails with a message that says `Invalid source`.

If i then look at F12 for more debugging info, it says:

> AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type

The content being rendered by the tag `src="abc"` is a wav file.

What am i missing? I am testing in IE11 and Chrome 43.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Does your `src=abc` file contains a extension, e.g. `abc.wav`?

Comment: Well in the end the text in my src should render a .wav file.

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be a popular question, I will explain what the error was and how i fixed it.

At first glance it might seem that setting the src property to a url link is not quite right, but it infact this url link renders me a wav file. However the wav could not by played by the HTML5 autio tag, because of its **encoding** **type**; That is, the encoding of the content of the wav file. This can be mulaw, alaw, linear etc. Alaw is not a supported format for HTML5, so I changed mine to Ulaw, and now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) suggests that WAV files are not supported by Internet Explorer and the only file type that works across most browsers is mp3.

I also faced this issue while using a .wav file. I converted it to .mp3 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://machinename/media/play?ID=2" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Comment: but that link is not video

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the HTML5 `<audio> ...</audio>` tags for your purposes.

A sample code for wav would be as follows:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="abc.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Currently, there are 3 supported file formats for the  element: MP3, Wav, and Ogg:

Chrome supports *MP3, Wav, and Ogg* formats, and Internet Explorer currently supports *MP3 only*, hence the possible invalid source error message you are seeing.

Simply convert all your wav files into mp3 and you should be safe for all browsers!

You can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i am following the format you suggest, and it is not working.

Comment: Check out your "src" tag, you need to point it to an actual wav file for it to work.

Comment: Daniel, what resource did you use to come to this conclusion?  Because the code in src is supposed to render a wav file.

Comment: I think you are missing the point that unixarmy and I are pointing. You need to change your src="https://machinename/media/play?ID=2" to something like src="../abc.wav". Your wav file would probably have to be also in the same web origin (i.e. located in your own hosting server). Test it out with a simple wav or mp3 file, this should work.

Comment: at the backend there is a server, the server looks at the url, specifically the ID part of it, and decides what audio wav file to render back to the browser. this enables me to playback audio files dynamically. so please - sorry - but no your answer does not help me.